# Can a notification service extension consume the notification and not display it to the user?

Tags: ios

I'd like to know if its possible for a notification service extension to have the push delivered to it, and then based on some state/settings of the app (which the app would have to have to make available to the extension via shared defaults for example) decide whether the notification should be displayed to the user or not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is prevented by Apple on purpose to prevent abuse of notification services for using them for other tasks other than displaying notifications.